# Operator> работает через раз

Tags: c++

У меня есть класс Lint "длинное целое число", вмещающее в себя целое число любой длины. Хранит он его в виде массива char, в каждом элементе массива содержится 2 разряда, но это не суть
В классе, помимо прочего, описан operator>, который, очевидно, определяет, больше одно число другого или нет.
Так вот, этот код работает:

```
string t,r;
cin >> t;
Lint ln (t);
ln.show();
cin >> r;
Lint lm(r);
int a;
cout << (lm>ln) << endl;
```

А этот нет, выдает ошибку, когда доходит до последней строки:

```
string t,r;
cin >> t;
Lint ln (t);
ln.show();
cin >> r;
Lint lm (r);

cout << (lm>ln) << endl;
```

Заметьте, я всего лишь убрал объявление переменной int a, которая вообще никаким боком не касается ни lm, ни ln, ни самого класса Lint.

Объясните, что здесь может быть не так, я уже отчаялся понять что-либо.

UPD: код Lint::operator>

```
bool Lint::operator> (Lint t)
{
    bool ret;
    if (!sign && t.sign) return 1;
    else{
        if (sign && !t.sign) return 0;
        else{
            if (size==t.size){
                int j = size-1;
                while(j >= 0 && num[j] == t.num[j]){j--;}
                if (j == -1) return 0;
                else{
                    int b1 = (int)num[j];
                    int h1 = b1 & 15;
                    int g1 = (b1 >> 4) & 15;
                    int c1 = g1*10+h1;

                    int b2 = (int)t.num[j];
                    int h2 = b2 & 15;
                    int g2 = (b2>>4) & 15;
                    int c2 = g2*10+h2;

                    if (c1 > c2) ret = 1;
                    else ret = 0;
                }
            }
            else{
                if (size > t.size) ret = 1;
                else ret = 0;
            }
            if (sign) ret=!ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Цифры хранятся в cимвольном массиве num, по 2 цифры в одном элементе, по одной в каждой половине байта.

UPD 2: ошибка в итоге решилась переписыванием функции operator>. Я сделал ее отдельной от класса Lint и объявил ее другом класса.

Сама функция:

```
bool operator> (xlInt& r, xlInt& t)
{
    bool ret;
    if (!r.sign && t.sign) return 1;
    else{
        if (r.sign && !t.sign) return 0;
        else{
            if (r.size == t.size){
                int j = r.size-1;
                while(j >= 0 && num[j] == t.num[j]){j--;}
                if (j == -1) return 0;
                else{
                    int b1 = (int)num[j];
                    int h1 = b1 & 15;
                    int g1 = (b1 >> 4) & 15;
                    int c1 = g1*10+h1;

                    int b2 = (int)t.num[j];
                    int h2 = b2 & 15;
                    int g2 = (b2>>4) & 15;
                    int c2 = g2*10+h2;

                    if (c1 > c2) ret = 1;
                    else ret = 0;
                }
            }
            else{
                if (r.size > t.size) ret = 1;
                else ret = 0;
            }
            if (r.sign) ret=!ret;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: а почему бы вам не привести код самого класса Lint?

Answer (score 1):

Код

```
while(num[j] == t.num[j]){j--;}
```

неверен: что будет, когда вы дойдёте до нуля? (Ответ: undefined behaviour.)

Исправляйте.

Кстати, логика с проверкой знака (`if (sign) ret=!ret;`) у вас тоже не сработает.

Comment: while исправил, спасибо.
Почему не будет работать if (sign) ret=!ret; , я не понял, извините.
Однако все это не отменяет вопроса: почему после объявления абсолютно левой переменной код срабатывает, а без объявления — нет?

Comment: я исправил указанные ошибки, однако это не помогло.
Правда, помогло другое: я переписал ее в качестве функции с двумя параметрами, не связанной с классом Lint (bool operator> (Lint& r, Lint& t)) и потом объявил ее как друга класса Lint, что волшебным образом избавило от всех проблем. В любом случае, спасибо за советы.

Comment: @bambimbom: Хм. Чудес на свете не бывает, если не работает, обязана быть ошибка. Опубликуйте код? Кстати, смена аргумента с `Lint t` на `Lint& t` — серьёзное, если у вас неправильный конструктор копирования.

Comment: @bambimbom: Ещё несколько ошибок:

1. Всё ещё undefined behaviour: в строке `int b1 = (int)r.num[j];` индекс `j` может быть `-1`.
2. До строки `if (r.sign) ret=!ret;` выполнение никогда не дойдёт. Можете убедиться сами.

Кстати, когда исправите, попробуйте вернуть оператор внутрь класса, только не забудьте аргумент передавать по ссылке.

Comment: Исправил ошибки.
А насчет вернуть внутрь класса, мне сказали, что, мол, так и надо и по стандарту внутрь класса ее заносить — атата.

Comment: @bambimbom: Вообще-то, если в вашем классе нету неявных преобразований (например, implicit-конструктора из `int`), должно быть всё равно. Стандарт по этому поводу никак не высказывается. Но в общем случае да, "внешний" friend-оператор лучше, т.к. он может неявно преобразовать _первый_ аргумент.

---
Но всё же, с исправлением ошибок проблема с оператором _внутри_ класса починилась?

Comment: Нет, изначальная ошибка осталась в случае с оператором внутри класса. В любом случае, все работает и особых компромиссов нет, поэтому проблема решена.

Comment: @bambimbom: Странно, это значит, ошибка осталась, и может в любой момент проявиться. Вы точно не забыли передать аргумент **по ссылке**?